# ANTLR ERROR : The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input

Tags: antlr, ebnf

I am new to ANTLR and I am trying the following .From the error it seems that I am defining something generic and the rule below it is unreachable/redundant.Redundant ones the ANTLR complains about is  **MAPPING,STROPS,UNARYOPS,ARITHEMATICOPS,MATHLOGICALOP,LOGICALOP,OP1,OP2,OP3,OP4** .I don't understand where exactly am I going wrong. Please let me know the issue and the concept behind it.

```
 grammar RA;

options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
  k=3;
}



DIVIDE : '/';
PLUS : '+';
MINUS : '-';
STAR : '*';
MOD : '%';
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
COMMA : ',';
COLON : ':';
LANGLEBRACKET : '<';
RANGLEBRACKET : '>';
EQ : '=';
NOT : '!';
UNDERSCORE : '_';
DOT : '.';
GRTRTHANEQTO : RANGLEBRACKET EQ;
LESSTHANEQTO : LANGLEBRACKET EQ;
NOTEQ         : NOT EQ;


fragment A:('a'|'A');
fragment B:('b'|'B');
fragment C:('c'|'C');
fragment D:('d'|'D');
fragment E:('e'|'E');
fragment F:('f'|'F');
fragment G:('g'|'G');
fragment H:('h'|'H');
fragment I:('i'|'I');
fragment J:('j'|'J');
fragment K:('k'|'K');
fragment L:('l'|'L');
fragment M:('m'|'M');
fragment N:('n'|'N');
fragment O:('o'|'O');
fragment P:('p'|'P');
fragment Q:('q'|'Q');
fragment R:('r'|'R');
fragment S:('s'|'S');
fragment T:('t'|'T');
fragment U:('u'|'U');
fragment V:('v'|'V');
fragment W:('w'|'W');
fragment X:('x'|'X');
fragment Y:('y'|'Y');
fragment Z:('z'|'Z');

AND     :   A N D;
OR      :   O R;
COUNT       :   C O U N T;
AVG     :   A V G;
COUNTDISTINCT   :   C O U N T D ;
CAST        :   C A S T;
CORRESPONDING   :   C O R R E S P O N D I N G;
ANY     :   A N Y;

MAPPING     :   (CORRESPONDING|ANY);
MATCHCASE       :   I;

EQUALS      :   E Q U A L S;
LIKE        :   L I K E;
NOTEQUALS       :                     N O T E Q U A L S;
NOTLIKE     :   N O T L I K E;
NOTNULL     :   N O T N U L L;

STROPS      :   (EQUALS | LIKE | NOTEQUALS | NOTLIKE | NOTNULL);
UNARYOPS        :   (COUNT | AVG | COUNTDISTINCT);
ARITHEMATICOPS  :   (DIVIDE|PLUS|MINUS|STAR|MOD);
MATHLOGICALOP   :   (LANGLEBRACKET|RANGLEBRACKET|EQ|GRTRTHANEQTO|LESSTHANEQTO|NOTEQ);
LOGICALOP       :   (AND|OR);

SECATTR     :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') UNDERSCORE? ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')* DOT ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') UNDERSCORE? ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')*;
BRACEDSECATTR   :   LPAREN SECATTR RPAREN;
UNOPSECATTR :   OP1 BRACEDSECATTR;

OP1     :   (UNARYOPS | CAST) ;
OP2     :   (ARITHEMATICOPS|MATHLOGICALOP|STROPS);
OP3     :   (MAPPING|MATCHCASE);
OP4     :   (LOGICALOP);
//fragment Letter : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
//Alphanumeric      :   (('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')| '0'..'9')* ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') (('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')| '0'..'9')* ;
SINGLERULE      :   (SECATTR|BRACEDSECATTR|UNOPSECATTR) OP2 ((('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')| '0'..'9')|SECATTR|BRACEDSECATTR|UNOPSECATTR);
BRACEDSINGLERULE    :   LPAREN SINGLERULE RPAREN;
UNOPSINGLERULE  :   BRACEDSINGLERULE OP3;

Expr        :   SINGLERULE|UNOPSINGLERULE|((SINGLERULE|UNOPSINGLERULE)OP4(SINGLERULE|UNOPSINGLERULE))+;
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it  : **MAPPING,STROPS,UNARYOPS,ARITHEMATICOPS,MATHLOGICALOP,LOGICALOP,OP1,OP2,OP3,OP4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR assigns one, and only one, token type (name starting with uppercase letter) to each non-overlapping sequence of characters in the input. In your case, the `ANY` rule matches a sequence, and the `MAPPING` rule defined after it is also defined to match `ANY` (as one of its alternatives). When the input is `any`, your lexer will *always* assign the token type `ANY` to it since that rule is defined first.

While you have allowed the input `any` to be a `MAPPING`, ANTLR is warning you that it will never assign the type `MAPPING` to this input, so the current definition of `MAPPING` is misleading. You should update your lexer rules so each sequence only matches one token type.

Comment: Thanks that helps . Though I wanted it to be as modular as possible , but I will work to improve it.